# Retrieving Sklearn typehints during runtime

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scikit-learn, typeshed

I am creating an app to train/use Sklearn models. The user should be able to select the various Sklearn models, at which point the arguments to the selected algorithm must be change-able by the user before training/running. To achieve this efficiently for all (future) Sklearn models, I want to retrieve the typehints and default values for the arguments to the methods during runtime and create the UI automatically based on these.

The Sklearn modules do not use type-hints, though VSCode autocomplete does 'know' the types and default values (from what I could find Vscode uses the Typeshed [but it seems to be difficult to access it during runtime](https://pypi.org/project/typeshed-client/)).

**In short**:
I want to pass [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) to *something* and receive:

```
(*, fit_intercept: bool = True, copy_X: bool = True, n_jobs: Int | None = None, positive: bool = False)
```

How would I go about receiving this information during runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Sklearn classes have a private variable called `_parameter_constraints` which contains a list of constraints for each parameter. In my case, it seems to be easiest to deduce the possible types and UI element from these constraints.

E.g., for linear regression:

```
_parameter_constraints: dict = {
 "fit_intercept": ["boolean"],
 "copy_X": ["boolean"],
 "n_jobs": [None, Integral],
 "positive": ["boolean"],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sklearn` uses [`numpy` docstrings](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html), so you can use [`numpydoc`](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) to get the [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.signature)

```
import sklearn.linear_model
from numpydoc.docscrape import ClassDoc

doc = ClassDoc(sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression)
sig = inspect.signature(sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression)
```

Usage:

```
>>> sig
<Signature (*, fit_intercept=True, copy_X=True, n_jobs=None, positive=False)>

>>> doc['Parameters']
[Parameter(name='fit_intercept', type='bool, default=True', desc=['Whether to calculate the intercept for this model. If set', 'to False, no intercept will be used in calculations', '(i.e. data is expected to be centered).']), 
 Parameter(name='copy_X', type='bool, default=True', desc=['If True, X will be copied; else, it may be overwritten.']),
 Parameter(name='n_jobs', type='int, default=None', desc=['The number of jobs to use for the computation. This will only provide', 'speedup in case of sufficiently large problems, that is if firstly', '`n_targets > 1` and secondly `X` is sparse or if `positive` is set', 'to `True`. ``None`` means 1 unless in a', ':obj:`joblib.parallel_backend` context. ``-1`` means using all', 'processors. See :term:`Glossary <n_jobs>` for more details.']),
 Parameter(name='positive', type='bool, default=False', desc=['When set to ``True``, forces the coefficients to be positive. This', 'option is only supported for dense arrays.', '', '.. versionadded:: 0.24'])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The only thing I don't like about this solution is that I will need to parse the `type` myself. Especially for more complex documentation this seems a bit hacky since I'm not sure what to take into account. For example: the "weights" argument of `sklearn.neighbors.KneighborsClassifier` returns `"{'uniform', 'distance'}, callable or None, default='uniform'"`, while VSCode returns this in a format that leaves less to be interpreted: `weights: ((...) -> Any) | Literal['uniform', 'distance'] | None = "uniform"`.